# Is there anyway to calculate a out of this equation?

Tags: logarithms

So I know that

$$a = e^\frac{\log_2(x)}{\ln x}$$.

(I couldn't find a link for formatting help, I'm sorry - 2 is the base, ^ = power).

Is there anyway to calculate a out of this?

Thanks.

Comment: Here it is https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Octavian Niculescu: Use the change-of-base formula.

Comment: @AndrewChin thanks a lot

Comment: @quasi I got it know after I looked into it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

By definition : $\log_2 x=\dfrac{\ln x}{\ln 2}$

Therefore your expression boils down to $a=e^{1/\log(2)}$ but it cannot be simplified further.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I will accept your answer asap.